# Run minicom after auto login and store serial data to a file

Tags: boot, serial

I want to save the serial data from `/dev/ttyUSB0` into a file (`.txt`) once I power on my Raspberry Pi. (Because I won't be connecting display or keyboard to Pi and I have to power off directly once my job is complete since I don't connect any display).

I tried to put these commands in `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0`.

```
 sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > file.txt & (using cat )

 sudo minicom -C file.txt &          (using minicom)
```

Nothing happens in both cases. No file is created.

Am I missing anything?

Can anybody suggest me any method for doing it?

Note: I'm using Raspberry Pi 2, Jessie

Comment: Hello and welcome. For starters: "->" is most likely wrong. Output redirection is just a `>`.

Comment: For `minicom`, well it's hard to tell as it uses a config file and we do not know the contents. Could be configure wrong, e.g. not using ttyUSB0 or a wrong baudrate and so on.

Comment: I used the same command by manually typing in command line, its works perfect. Only when I put it in  /etc/rc.local nothing happens

Comment: And sorry about "->". It is not required as you said.

Comment: When you say “*I have to power off directly once my job is complete*”, are you shutting the Raspberry Pi down properly, or pulling the plug? The latter will result in your files getting corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Use [grabserial](https://github.com/tbird20d/grabserial). It's designed for logging serial information. You'd run it something like this:

```
grabserial -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 38400 > file.txt
```

You don't need to use `sudo` in rc.local. It's run as root anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that minicom doesn't work when run as background job. Had the same issue. I ended up launching a terminal at startup (using autostart & lxterminal) and letting it open while running minicom. 
To set it up :

- `sudo nano /home/pi/.config/autostart/minicom.desktop`
- paste this to open a terminal at startup and run a script

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Name=minicom
  Terminal=true
  Hidden=false
  Exec=lxterminal -e sudo /home/pi/startupscript
  ```
- save and exit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- `sudo nano /home/pi/startupscript`
- paste this
  `minicom -b 230400 -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -C /home/pi/out.txt`
- save and exit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- reboot and you should seen the terminal opened with minicom running